# is taking the dot product of matrices the same thing as "multiplying" them together?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

U is a matrix.
is U dot product U the same thing as UU?

so if i see U(transpose)U next to each other, is that the same thing as U(transpose) x U and the same thing as U(transpose) dot product U?

Sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: By the "dot product" of matrices, what do you mean? This is not a common notion as far as I know. If you mean to take $\sum_{ij} a_{ij}b_{ij}$ where $A = (a_{ij})$ and $B = (b_{ij})$, then this would not be the same thing as $AB$ unless both matrices were $1\times 1$.

Answer (score 1):

The *inner product* (or *dot product*) of vectors $u =(u_1,\ldots, u_n)$ and $v=(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ in $\mathbb R^n$ is given by
$$u \cdot v = u_1v_1+\cdots +u_nv_n.$$
It is defined for vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ rather than matrices, so your question about whether $UU$ is the same as the dot product of $U$ with itself doesn't really make sense. There is a notion of an inner product for matrices, namely the Frobenius inner product (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product) given by
$$\langle A, B \rangle = \operatorname{Tr}(A^*B)$$
for complex matrices $A, B$, but this is typically not seen in an introductory linear algebra course.

Lastly, you are right, the expression $U^TU$ does refer to the transpose of U multiplied by U, where 'multiplied' refers to the usual matrix multiplication.

Comment: thank you for the clarification. this was a confusion on my end. thanks!